# assert isinstance(address, (tuple, list, str)), "tuple or str expected" AssertionError: tuple or str expected

Tags: python, django, async-await, asyncsocket, django-channels

I am working on a django project in which I included django channels but I getting this error. I have tried to fix the bug but the problem is that I can not really find where my program has issues.

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from Forecast.models import*
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync #this is to help us convert the 
asyncrounous request to a syncronous one

class Home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        houses = House.objects.all()
        context={'houses':houses}
        layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(layer.group_send)(
            'visted', {
            'type':'homepage.visted',
            'event':'new visit',
            'username':request.user.username
            })
        return render(request,'accounts/base.html',context)
```

Then this below is my consumer.py

```
#consumer.py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import asyncio

class TestConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        #this accepts the connection
        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('visted', self.channel_name)
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await self.send(text_data='you have been connected')
    async def receive(self, test_data=None, byte_data=None):
        #this handles all received data
        await self.send(text_data= 'we got your message')
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await self.close()
    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard('visited', self.channel_name)
    async def hompage_visted(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=event['message'])
```

finally my routing.py, asgi routing file

```
#routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.urls import path
from .consumer import TestConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
        path('testsocket/', TestConsumer)
        ])
        )
    })
```

but just like as I said I keep getting this error below which I found out has a link to my views.py, yet I can not figure out what is wrong with the code

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Projects\Hagent\Hagent\views.py" in get
  18.           'username':request.user.username

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\asgiref\sync.py" in __call__
  64.         return call_result.result()

File
"C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\
futures\_base.py" in result
  432.                 return self.__get_result()

File
"C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\
futures\_base.py" in __get_result
  384.             raise self._exception

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\asgiref\sync.py" in main_wrap
  78.             result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\channels_redis-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\channels_redis\core.py" in 
group_send
  601.         async with self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group)) as 
connection:

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\channels_redis-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\channels_redis\core.py" in 
__aenter__
  813.             self.conn = await self.pool.pop()

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\channels_redis-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\channels_redis\core.py" in pop
  70.             conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, 
loop=loop))

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\aioredis-1.2.0-py3.6.egg\aioredis\commands\__init__.py" in 
create_redis
  178.                                    loop=loop)

File "C:\Users\LIVINUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\aioredis-1.2.0-py3.6.egg\aioredis\connection.py" in 
create_connection
  77.     assert isinstance(address, (tuple, list, str)), "tuple or str 
expected"

Exception Type: AssertionError at /
Exception Value: tuple or str expected
```

in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #django specific apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #here are my own apps
    'Account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'Forecast.apps.ForecastConfig',
    #here are third party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'AutoTags',
    'channels',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = os.path.split(BASE_DIR)[1]+'.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = os.path.split(BASE_DIR)[1]+'.routing.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    'default':{
            'BACKEND':'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
            'CONFIG':{
            'hosts':['localhost', 6379]
            }
    },
}
```

Comment: Show your `settings.py` config also please

Comment: This error doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code you have posted, but in the settings for Redis. Please show those.

Comment: I have included the settings

Comment: @Nolwac, in your `settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS` change `['localhost', 6379]` to `[('localhost', 6379)]`

Comment: wow! thanks a lot, I can't believe I did not notice that. sharing a problem is indeed the best. Thanks once more

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was in incorrect `settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS` variable.

`hosts` should be a list that *contains* a tuple.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    'default': {
        'BACKEND':'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG':{
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        }
    },
}
```

[Reference](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#configuration)

Comment: I know this post is nearly a year old but you saved me hours of troubleshooting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What @Satevg said is exactly correct. It should be a list with tuples.

But at times there are some issues with using localhost.

It's better to have the IP instead.

```
  CHANNEL_LAYERS={
  'default': {
      'BACKEND':'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
      'CONFIG':{
          'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
      }
   },                                                                    
}
```